# textscan() failing for large file

Tags: matlab, machine-learning

I am trying to import data from a very large mixed values csv file. My below code works fine without the textscan(). But with textscan() it freezes at random points.

```
function untitled3()
    fileName='TestNetworkData.csv';
    fid=fopen(fileName);
    while(1)
       str=fgetl(fid);
       disp(str);
       if(str==-1)
           break;
       end
       x = textscan(str,'%d %n %s %s %s %[^\n]s', 'delimiter', '", ', 'MultipleDelimsAsOne', 1);
       disp(x);
    end

end
```

How do I debug the issue for freezing? Any alternative methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find no real solution for this problem. csvread() should have helped but since the csv files has both string and numeric values it is not really usefull. Adding a clearvars() after disp(x) solved problem for some time but again it started showing problems.

Finally my solution was to import csv data using the wizard in Matlab. It may take a few minutes but once its done store the imported variable into a .mat file. This we can load it when required in much less time.